# PyQt5 - update QAbstractTableModel and retrieve Data

Tags: python-3.x, model-view-controller, pyqt

I'm currently building a GUI Application to assist me in searching for Peaks in a Spectrum. I have implemented the Matplotlib in such a matter, that i can click onto the Peaks to load them into a list.

This List I want to display next to the Graph. To do that I try to utilize the Table View Widget of PyQt.

I have no Problem populating the Widget but I would like to automatically update the widget when the dictionary changes and automatically update the dictionary when I edit the Data in the widget.

So far I use this custom Model to populate the Widget and make it editable:

```py
class DictModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Custom Table Model to handle RUS Data
    """

    def __init__(self, data):
        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)
        self.user_data = data
        self.columns = list(self.user_data.keys())

    def flags(self, index): #, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return max(len(val) for val in self.user_data.values())

    def columnCount(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return(len(self.columns))

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.columns[section]

    def data(self, index, role):
        column = self.columns[index.column()]
        #set the value for the row but return None if the Index is out of range
        row = self.user_data[column][index.row()] if index.row() < len(self.user_data[column]) else ""
        try:
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                return str(row)
        except KeyError:
            return None
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            selected_column = self.columns[index.column()]
            self.user_data[selected_column][index.row()] = value
            return True
```

when I display a little bit of data like so it works fine

```py
    self.testData = {
            'C1':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'C2':[2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
            'C3':[4, 8, 16, 32,64],
            }

    def testTable(self, data):
        self.testModel = DictModel(data)
        self.tableViewTest.setModel(testModel)

    # I suspect something along the lines of this should update my model? This doesnt change it
    def testEditData(self):
        self.testModel.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self.testData['new'] = ['new']
        self.testModel.layoutChanged.emit()
```

I can call the testTable funciton again with a new Dataset but I guess this would not be the Ideal way to go about it, right?

Does anyone of you have a hint on how to sync the dictionary and the View with each other? I have searched for quite some time now and there seems to be no clear example on how to do that. I did not find any well understandable guides to the model.layoutChanged.emit() methods or any Information on how to get the Information back out of the model into a dataframe or dictionary.

Comment: While the documentation is not completely clear about this point, "layout change" functions and signals should *not* be used when the model size changes (row/column count): the layout changes are about how *existing* items are being laid out, which is what happens when, for example, a column is being sorted. The proper way to deal with model size changes is to implement `insertRows()` and `removeRows()` (and the same for columns, if that matters). The real question is: you're using a dict, which since Python 3.6 follows insertion order, but do you want to follow that pattern?

Comment: Well in theory I'd like to utilize a real database like SQlite but since I'm not really versed in this area I tried to start with python native objects. And since I'm adding and removing data points all the time I thought a dictionary would be the best approach.

Comment: Ok, but remember that even if Python 3.7 maintains the insertion order, it will not be preserved whenever you remove and add again the same key, and you cannot "insert" new items at a certain index, as they can only be replaced or added to the end, so a list is normally the preferred choice. That said, you cannot "automatically sync" the dict (or list) data, you have to implement that on your own. Also, be aware that Qt provides the QtSql module; while learning how Qt models work is certainly educational, if you only need basic read/write access to a database, you should use that instead.

Comment: Very well, this is a good tip. Thank you for your time.